# OpenCV cropped image distorted

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read an image and crop a rectangular region from it using OpenCV.  However the cropped image I'm getting seems to be out of proportion and not the same size as the original.  Is there something wrong with my code? Or am I doing something stupid like unintentionally zooming in on the window. Ran on ubuntu.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Read in an image 1
    Mat Cloud1 = imread("/home/user1/Pictures/cloud1.jpeg");
    Rect rect(250,250,150,150); //some random values
    Mat Template = Cloud1(rect);
    namedWindow("FIGURE 1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("FIGURE 2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("FIGURE 1", Cloud1);
    imshow("FIGURE 2", Template);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**Update**:  Nevermind I think it's a display issue because when I darkened the template `Template = 1.0f * Template - 20`, the original image was correctly modified.

Comment: Wierd... Code seems fine..

Comment: That is may be due to `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE `, However it shouldn't be, But I have experienced `imshow` behaving unexpectedly, so kindly  save the image at a specified location and examine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but isn't what you are doing just resizing to new bounds?

In openCV you need to set a region of interest and create a new image from the ROI.